# Model category that doesn't admit functorial factorizations?

Tags: category-theory, homotopy-theory, model-categories

I guess it's a modern convention that model categories are typically required to have functorial factorizations. In the cofibrantly generated case, the factorizations constructed by the small object argument are functorial. And [Riehl and Barthel](http://msp.org/agt/2013/13-2/p15.xhtml) are able to relax even that requirement.

But the question remains: what's an example of a model category in the non-functorial sense which doesn't admit functorial factorizations?

Comment: The category of bounded chain complexes of finitely generated abelian groups.

Comment: Could you elaborate / provide a reference? This category is only finitely complete and cocomplete, right? And I suppose that must be what it comes down to?

Comment: I've never seen a proof, but it is the example that is always cited. The point, I suppose, is that none of the usual machinery can be used – not even the ancient constructions of free resolutions.